# Return false if char is repeated

Tags: vb.net, string, datagridview

I'm coding in a DataGridView, and validating if the cell has a format of numbers and comma only, the cell is for document pages,
sample format that would return true, or accept: 1,2 or 1,2,5 BUT NOT 1,,2 or 1,,,6,2

I have made a function for that, and it works fine, BUT I'm not comfortable using my code, I hope there is a better code than I have.

Please correct my code for better.

Thanks.

```
Private Function isCELLPageNumb(ByRef valyo As String, ByVal origMaxPage As String) As Boolean
    If valyo = "0" Or valyo = "," Then
        valyo = origMaxPage 
        Return False
    End If
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789,"
    For i As Integer = (valyo.Length - 1) To 0 Step -1
        If allowedChars.IndexOf(valyo(i)) = -1 Then
            valyo = origMaxPage 
            Return False
        End If
        Try
            If valyo(i) = "," Then
                If valyo(i + 1) = "," Then
                    valyo = origMaxPage 
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            valyo = origMaxPage 
            Return False
        End Try

        ''I THINK I HAVE TO SEE IF THE COMMA NEXT NUMBER IS GREATER THAN THE MAXPAGE
        ''If valyo(i)>origMaxPage then
        ''End If 

    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Edited the origMaxPage

```
Private Function isCELLPageNumb(ByRef valyo As String, ByVal origMaxPage As String) As Boolean
    If valyo = "0" Or valyo = "," Then
        valyo = origMaxPage
        Return False
    End If


    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789,"
    For i As Integer = (valyo.Length - 1) To 0 Step -1

        ''IF ALLOWED CHARACTERS NOT IN THE INDEX
        If allowedChars.IndexOf(valyo(i)) = -1 Then
            valyo = origMaxPage
            Return False
        End If

        Try
            ''IF VALYO IS COMMA REPEATED
            If valyo(i) = "," Then
                If valyo(i + 1) = "," Then
                    valyo = origMaxPage
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            valyo = origMaxPage
            Return False
        End Try

        Try
            ''IF VALYO GREATHER THAN THE MAXPAGE
            If valyo(i) = "," Then
                Dim twodigit As String = valyo(i + 1) & valyo(i + 2)
                Dim numtwodigit As UInt32 = Val(twodigit)
                If numtwodigit > origMaxPage Then
                    valyo = origMaxPage
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            valyo = origMaxPage
            Return False
        End Try

    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

The problem of the code, what if the maxpage is 12, then the user inputed 1,3,5,1111
?

The input may NOT accept negative number like: -1 or -123

Thanks

Comment: Can there be double digit numbers?  Like 10 or 11?

Comment: @MackieChan,  Yes, there is,  thanks for asking.  eq., 1,2,10,15

Comment: I have not tested it yet, to accept all your answer as good and checked, because everyone helped me, I'll try to after this post is covered.  thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined to [MackieChan solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013351/2387010) to parse integer, you should use first [**Regex**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx)

```
private rgxNumberWithComma As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^([0-9]+,?)+$")
Public Function CheckInput(ByVal valyo As String, _
             ByVal origMaxPage As Integer) As Boolean

Dim match = rgxNumberWithComma.Match(valyo)
If Not match.Success Then
    Return False
Else
    Dim numbers as new List(Of Integer) ‘will store added numbers
    For Each Item In valyo.Split(","c)
        Dim intValue As Integer
        ‘Check if number is a valid integer
        ‘Check if number is 0
        ‘Check if number has already added the number list
        ‘Check if number is greater that MaxPage
        If Not Integer.TryParse(Item, intValue) _
                   OrElse intValue > origMaxPage _
                   OrElse intValue = 0 _
                   OrElse numbers.Contains(IntValue) Then
            Return False
        Else
            ‘Item is valid, continue
            Numbers.Add(intValue)    
        End If
    Next
End If
Return True
End Function
```

See [Need a Regex for comma separated number list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739919/need-a-regex-for-comma-separated-number-list)

Comment: its good, but with maxpage of 12, when I input 1,2,5,12,12 it accepts, but it seems 12,12 has been repeated.  And also when I input 1,0 it accepts also, where 0 is invalid input.  Thanks, I'll wait for your other solution, and I will not modify the code of yours until you have another solution.

Comment: @Blaise If you have basic programming knowledge, you should be able to change the code in order to add other check points. For example, in the second part of the function, you can test if the a value contains 0 or if it is a duplicate number. I have updated the sample.

Comment: Hello, here's the continuetion >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513067/inputting-page-manually-by-comma-and-range-negative-sign-using-regex

Answer (score 2):

I assume that at some point you're going to need to get the page numbers anyways, so you should start with that:

```
Public Function ParsePageNumbers(value As String, maxPage As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim values As New List(Of Integer)()


        For Each strNumber As var In value.Split(","C)
            Dim intValue As Integer
            ' if it wasn't an integer or it's greater than the max page, restore the original value
            If Not Integer.TryParse(strNumber, intValue) OrElse intValue > maxPage Then
                Return Nothing
            End If

            values.Add(intValue)
        Next

        Return values
    End Function
```

This function will return `Nothing` if the pages numbers have invalid values.  Then in your actual method you can just call this method and check for `Nothing`:

```
Private Function isCELLPageNumb(ByRef valyo As String, ByVal origValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim maxPage As Integer = Integer.Parse(origMaxPage)
        ' if it's not parsible, restore the original value
        If ParsePageNumbers(value, maxPage) Is Nothing Then
            value = origMaxPage
            Return False
        End If

        ' it was all valid
        Return True
End Function
```

Comment: And also the cell may NOT contain negative digit like: -1 or 0.0.1 or 0,  I'll get back soon, sorry, but thanks.

Comment: You can do any extra checking in the `ParsePageNumbers` method and return `Nothing` if it doesn't fit your criteria.

Comment: OK, for now I can't add a point for all of you, but I think I have to select which one has the right and good solution, but it seems everyone has contributed more. So, I will not CLICK the Check until I am able to add points.  thanks to ALL.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in your Datagridview EditingControlShowing Event ...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Try

        If UCase(sCellName) = "PAGENUM" '------> change this with yours

             AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf PageKeypress

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        '... 
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub PageKeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Static sLast As String = ""
    Dim k As Byte = Asc(e.KeyChar)
    Dim sN As String = "0123456789,"
    Dim sO As String = Chr(8) & Chr(13) & Chr(1) & Chr(3) & Chr(22)

    Dim nMaxPage As Integer = 12 '-------change this with yours

    If Not (sN & sO).Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    Else
        Select Case e.KeyChar
            Case ","
                If sLast = "," Then
                    e.Handled = True
                Else
                    e.Handled = False
                    sLast = ","
                End If
                Exit Sub
            Case "0"
                If sLast = "," Or sLast = "" Then
                    e.Handled = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Case Chr(13) '-- avoid "," in end of text OR YOU CAN REMOVE THIS
                If sLast = "," Then e.Handled = True
        End Select
        If sLast = "," Then sLast = ""
        If Val(sLast & e.KeyChar) > nMaxPage Then
            e.Handled = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sLast &= IIf(sN.Contains(e.KeyChar), e.KeyChar, "")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: your solution accepts repeated commma like: 1,,,, ,it also accepts 1,13 which is greater than the maxpage is 12, it does not accept backspace, it also accepts 1,0 which is 0 is not accepted, it also accepts 1,012,12 which is 12 is the maxpage, thanks for trying but I like your idea using the EditingControlShowing.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong with the code, but it accepts: 1,2,4,12,12,12,12, I'll be back in this post to add you points, thanks.

Comment: @blaise : sorry I forgot blocking same pagenum .. you can modify the **Sub PageKeyPress** .. but I dont think you need this anymore ..

Comment: thanks, I've already add points to you, and glad to know about your code.