# Inputting page manually by comma and range negative sign using Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to change or update the code from detecting commas for pages,

The code below shows how to input pages with commas,

sample: 1,2,5,3,8 and it would not accept 0, or greater than the maximum page

What I'm asking is to add the code that would accept 
like this:

2-5,8,9
or
8,9,2-5
or
2-5,8-10

so it means, pages to print are 2,3,4,5,8,9,10

**BUT it will NOT accept input like 2-5,4,8,9 because 4 was already used in 2-5**

if that could be hard then its ok to input a simple range like: 
2-5 and no commas, so user could not input commas, if they want to input 
comma then the -sign could not be input also.

```
''CODED By: Chris, Combined to MackieChan solution    
Public Function isCELLPageNumb(ByRef valyo As String, ByVal origMaxPage As Integer) As Boolean
   Dim rgxNumberWithComma As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^([0-9]+,?)+$")
   Dim match = rgxNumberWithComma.Match(valyo)
   If Not match.Success Then
      Return False
   Else

      Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer) 'will store added numbers
      For Each Item In valyo.Split(","c)
         Dim intValue As Integer
         'Check if number is a valid integer
         'Check if number is 0
         'Check if number has already added the number list
         'Check if number is greater that MaxPage
         If Not Integer.TryParse(Item, intValue) _
         OrElse intValue > origMaxPage _
         OrElse intValue = 0 _
         OrElse numbers.Contains(intValue) Then
            Return False
         Else
            'Item is valid, continue
            numbers.Add(intValue)
         End If
      Next
   End If
   Return True
End Function   


Private Sub DbGridPapers_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DbGridPapers.CellEndEdit

   Dim pagestoprint As String = Nothing

   Try
      pagestoprint = DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
   Catch ex As Exception
   End Try

   If (e.ColumnIndex = 1) And (pagestoprint IsNot Nothing) Then    
      If Not isCELLPageNumb(DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value, OrigPage(e.RowIndex)) Then
         MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", "INVALID INPUT FOR [PAGES] AT ROW " & (e.RowIndex).ToString)
         DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = OrigPage(e.RowIndex)
         Return
      Else
         MyThreadedControl(lbltest, "Text", "The Maximum Page is:" & OrigPage(e.RowIndex).ToString)
      End If

      Dim pageDest As String = Nothing
      If Me.btnpaperpay.Enabled Then
         pageDest = DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Tag & "\"
      Else
         pageDest = docPrintnationPath & "\"
      End If

      Dim filename As String = pageDest & DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).HeaderCell.Value.ToString
      Dim OldRegularPrice As Decimal = DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value
      Dim FILEpages As New List(Of Integer)

      ''IF , AND - CAN BE MIX TO GET THE PAGE THEN ITS BETTER, AND I HAVE TO UPDATE THE CODE HERE ALSO.

      If pagestoprint.Split(",").Length > 1 Then 'Split Length is +1 based
         Dim pageFILES() As String = pagestoprint.Split(",")
         For Each filePids As Integer In pageFILES
            FILEpages.Add(filePids) ''GET range in comma sample page1,page3,page8,page2
         Next
      ElseIf pagestoprint.Split("-").Length > 1 Then 'Split Length is +1 based
         Dim pageFILES() As String = pagestoprint.Split("-")              
         For page As Integer = pageFILES(0) To pageFILES(1)    
            FILEpages.Add(page) ''GET range sample pages2 to page5
         Next
      Else
         Dim pages As Integer
         If (Integer.TryParse(pagestoprint, pages)) Then
            If pages = OrigPage(e.RowIndex) Then
               DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = OrigImage(e.RowIndex)
               DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = OrigPay(e.RowIndex)
               DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value = OrigCountedImage(e.RowIndex)
               GoTo pCounter ''Return Original Cells Value
            Else
               FILEpages.Add(pages)''GET single page only
            End If
          End If
       End If   

pCounter:
       Dim paperToTpay As Decimal = txtpapertotpay.Text.Substring(0, txtpapertotpay.Text.LastIndexOf(" ")) 
       paperToTpay -= OldRegularPrice
       paperToTpay += DbGridPapers.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value
       MyThreadedControl(txtpapertotpay, "Text", paperToTpay.ToString & " dollar(s)")
    End If 
End Sub
```

I think its very hard.

Comment: Would you accept a solution based on custom string analysis, rather than on regular expressions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you commented your code to help others understand it. Also your first two sample texts don't include a `10` so they don't exactly align with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that a custom algorithm is acceptable. Here you have an approach accounting for all the described conditions:

```
Private Function extractPages(ByVal inputString As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim outList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    If (inputString.Contains(",")) Then
        outList = extractCommas(inputString, outList)
    ElseIf (inputString.Contains("-")) Then
        outList = extractDashes(inputString, outList)
    End If

    If (outList.Count > 0) Then
        For i As Integer = outList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If (outList.IndexOf(outList(i)) <> outList.LastIndexOf(outList(i))) Then
                'Repeated item
                'It can be just deleted or shall the function return an error?
                outList.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return outList
End Function

Private Function extractCommas(ByVal inputString As String, curList As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)

    If (inputString.Contains(",")) Then
        Dim temp() As String = inputString.Split(",")
        For Each item In temp
            If (Not item.Contains("-") And IsNumeric(item)) Then
                If (Convert.ToInt32(item.Trim()) > 0) Then
                    curList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.Trim()))
                End If
            ElseIf (item.Contains("-")) Then
                curList = extractDashes(item.Trim(), curList)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return curList
End Function

Private Function extractDashes(ByVal inputString As String, curList As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)

    If (inputString.Contains("-")) Then
        Dim temp() = inputString.Split("-")
        If (temp.Length = 2) Then
            If (Convert.ToInt32(temp(0)) <= Convert.ToInt32(temp(1))) Then
                Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(temp(0)) - 1
                If (count < 0) Then
                    count = 0
                End If
                Do
                    count = count + 1
                    curList.Add(count)
                Loop While (count < Convert.ToInt32(temp(1)))
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return curList
End Function
```

You can call `extractPages` and get all the page numbers:

```
Dim InputString As String = "2-5, 4,8-10"
Dim allPages As List(Of Integer) = extractPages(InputString) 'It returns 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10
```

Comment: Ok, I got the codes, but, it seems there's no error trapping if I input a string it errors, imagine if there are 9 pages then i input 10 it accept the number which is not good. what i really want is to add some codes to the "isCELLPageNumb" function that accept - sign.

Comment: I have made the code such that it only allows through the specific conditions it is designed to deal with. It would ignore anything other than strings consisting in numbers and/or "-" and/or ",". In its current version, it is already highly reliable; in any case, I haven't analysed each single possible scenario: firstly because you are the one knowing better what might be inputted and secondly because (as 1min ago said somewhere else), I don't intend to fix problems for others, just to provide some help to programmers facing a  problem. The alternative I proposed is (out of space...)

Comment: (continue) completely different to the one you were using and this is the help I intended to provided: a different way to face your problem which, in my opinion, is much more adaptable/extensible, etc. You can use my code as it is (as said, already works pretty nicely), but what I was expecting (/would have done in your situation) is you to take it and adapt it and even improve it; that is, taking the knowledge/alternative way to face the problem, rather than the code itself. In any case, if you need further help to understand/improve/extend my code, you are free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

It's not exactly clear what you're looking for, but this powershell solution shows the logic behind how I would approach the problem to allow a user to input `0,2-5,4,8,9` so that the zero and extra redundant digits are ignored.

**Example**

```
$string = "0,2-5,4,8,9"

[hashtable]$hashPages = @{}

foreach ($chunk in $String -split ",") {

    # if the string has a dash then process it as a range
    if ($chunk -match "(\d+)-(\d+)") {
        # itterate through all the pages in the range
        foreach ($Page in $Matches[1] .. $Matches[2]) {
            # insert this page into a hash, which will keep the numbers unique
            $hashPages[[string]$Page] = $true
            } # next page
        } # end if

    # if string is only a number then process it as a single number
    if ($chunk -match "(\d+)") {
        # insert this page into a hash, which will keep the numbers unique
        $hashPages[[string]$Matches[1]] = $true
        } # end if

    } # next chunk

# remove the undesireable numbers like zero if they were added
$hashPages.Remove("0");

Write-Host "these pages where requested:" $(($hashPages.Keys | sort ) -join ",")
```

**Output**

```
these pages where requested: 2,3,4,5,8,9
```